# How can I delete mesh parts with python?

Tags: scripting, mesh

Suppose I have identified or can identifiy some meshparts I no longer want in my mesh and want to delete them, how would I do it?

I know that bmesh.ops.delete exists, I just don't know how to use it, because the API is a bit lacking for that function. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using the bmesh simple template from the text editor, and a bit of snooping around. You should experiment with the `geom` and `context` parameters.

The context is enumerated so ([source: bmesh_operator_api.h](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_operator_api.h)):

```
enum {
DEL_VERTS = 1,
DEL_EDGES,
DEL_ONLYFACES,
DEL_EDGESFACES,
DEL_FACES,
DEL_ALL,
DEL_ONLYTAGGED
};
```

This example assumes we have a mesh object in edit-mode and several faces selected. Running the script will delete edges and faces associated with the selection.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
faces_select = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select] 

bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=faces_select, context=5)  

# Show the updates in the viewport
# and recalculate n-gon tessellation.
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

Comment: What are the differences between DEL_ONLYFACES, DEL_EDGESFACES and DEL_FACES?

Comment: those are the same options you get if you try to delete geometry using X in the viewport,  ONLYFACES keeps edges (and verts), EDGESFACES just keeps verts, ...etc..