# How can I delete polygons with negative y coordinates?

Tags: python, scripting

I'd like to delete the polygons which normals have negative y coordinates. With this script I can have the vector representing polygon's normal displayed:

```
import bpy

current_obj = bpy.context.active_object

print("="*40) # printing marker
for polygon in current_obj.data.polygons:
    verts_in_face = polygon.vertices[:]
    norm = polygon.normal
    print("face index", polygon.index)
    print("normal", polygon.normal)
```

My problem is that **I simply can't check for y coordinate of this vector**: I've tried:

```
polygon.normal[1]
polygon.normal.y
```

etc. I'm getting "Syntax error: invalid syntax" pointing at [1] or .y. In this case, it isn't possible to check vector's y coordinate against 0 in if statement, so I can't pick up the vectors which y coords are >=0.

Comment: what is the full error message.

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else, the code works for me. I can even check `polygon.normal.y > 0`. There is a syntax error in your code, can you show the code?

Comment: @Jerryno - my full code was posted above except if(polygon.normal.y > 0) above last two lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're asking for is this:

#### Using ops

```
import bpy

# if named..
# obj = bpy.data.objects['IcoSphere']  
obj = bpy.context.active_object  
me = obj.data

# must be in object mode, to refresh face selections and data
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT') 

faces = me.polygons
for f in faces:
    f.select = (f.normal.y < 0.0)

# to remove using this method we switch to edit mode, and back after removal.

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

This is essentially a scripted walk through of what you would be doing if you inspected each face normal and selected only those that had a negative y coordinate, then at the end it would delete the selected faces.

There are other ways to do this, but this might give some insight. This is the after shot:

[image]

#### Using bmesh

See:

- TextEditor -> Templates -> Python -> Bmesh Simple
- [bmesh.ops docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bmesh.ops.html?highlight=bmesh#bmesh.ops.delete).

warning, the *context* parameter of bmesh.ops delete is a little undocumented, but is described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1542/47)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.active_object  
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh

faces = [f for f in bm.faces if (f.normal.y < 0.0)]

bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=faces, context=5)

# Finish up, write the bmesh back to the mesh
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()  # free and prevent further access
```