# Argument values in `bmesh.ops.similar_verts()`

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

Can someone please help me understand the values for the arguments in the function `bmesh.ops.simlar_verts(bm, verts, type, thresh, compare)`

I understand that:
`bm`- is the bmesh you are working on
`verts`- is a list of BMVerts to base the selection on
`thresh`- is some kind of distance based threshold

But what on earth do the int values for `type` and `compare` relate to?

I have played around with the values and have noted they select different patterns of vertices but I can't figure out the pattern. The [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html?highlight=limited%20dissolve#bmesh.ops.similar_verts) don't appear to have any information for the values.

If you can explain to me what these values relate to or point me in the direction of an answer I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check the source where docs are lacking.**

[Similarly to this answer re `bmesh.ops.delete`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1542/15543) look at source of *`bmesh/intern/bmesh_operators.h`*

On compare

```
enum {
    SIM_CMP_EQ = 0,
    SIM_CMP_GT,
    SIM_CMP_LT
};
```

The int enum values for equality is 0, greater than 1, and less than 2.

On types

```
/* similar vertex selection slot values */
enum {
    SIMVERT_NORMAL = 0,
    SIMVERT_FACE,
    SIMVERT_VGROUP,
    SIMVERT_EDGE
};
```

On types it appears to check, 0 checks normals, 1 linked faces, 2 vertex group, and 3 linked edges.

**Note**

The bmesh similar operators appear to have been removed from 2.8

Comment: Ok, so I've taken your advice and checked the source code mentioned and the file `source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_operators.h`. Your evaluation of the values for `compare` appear to be correct. `type` has one extra value at the beginning of the enum for 'normals'. I have tested this again and it now makes sense. Thanks for you response!

Comment: Cool, glad you sorted it. wondered about that since normals are mentioned in docs.  Apologies Had to rush off so posted a bit half-assed.  [Similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1542/15543)

Answer (score 1):

So building upon @batFingers answer and diving into the source code as suggested, the following values for `compare` and `type` are:

`compare`
0 - Equal to
1 - Greater than
2 - Less than

`type`
0 - Normals . . (The angle between normals)
1 - Faces . . (The number of adjacent faces)
2 - Vertex Group . . (Only search within the vertex group)
3 - Edges . . (The number of adjacent edges)

---

For example, if you have a basic grid and go:

`mesh.ops.similar_verts(yourBmesh, verts=[aCornerVert], type=1, thresh=0.0, compare=0)`

This will look at the number of adjacent faces(`type=1`) equal to(`compare=0`) the vert inputted, which in our case is a corner vert(I used 99). Each corner vert of the grid only has one adjacent face and so therefor each corner vert will be returned from this call.

[image: An image captured from Blenders 3D viewport showing the resulting corner vertices being selected]

---

If you go:

`mesh.ops.similar_verts(yourBmesh, verts=[anEdgeVert], type=3, thresh=0.0, compare=0)`

This will search the number of adjacent edges to the vert and/or verts supplied. Again, if you supplied a single vert from our grid(I used 89) which is on an edge but not a corner(has three adjacent edges) then all other verts with 3 adjacent edges will also be selected.

[image: An image captured from Blenders 3D viewport showing the resulting edge vertices being selected]